# How to type Japanese chōonpu "ー" long sound mark on Android?

Tags: japanese

How do you write the "ー" prolonged sound character (as in コート) on Android?

I'm trying to learn Japanese, and I'm using Google's "Gboard" app as my keyboard, and I can't find this character anywhere, making it impossible to write any word that contains it.

Some posts I've found claim you can just write "coat" and Gboard will auto-correct it to "コート", but I've found this is incorrect. If I write the English word in the Romanji version of the keyboard, it auto-suggests nothing.

Some posts say to write hiragana "こ-と", using the minus sign as a stand-in, and again it should auto-correct it, but again, Gboard corrects or suggests nothing.

The three keyboard layouts I get from pressing the "あa1" key are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I type "こ-と" using the hyphen/minus key, I get these suggestions:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?